# How to fix overlapping text in table cells?

Tags: html, css

I have a `<td>` containing an `<a>` tag and what seems to be reoccurring is that the last few characters (1~4) will not show up as part of the hyperlink (not underlined, not click-able, but color is blue).  Is there a CSS/JS fix for this?
It looks like this (with the c, e, s also being blue) .

With the next cell overlapping the part that isn't part of the hyperlink, similarly to this:

[My Link That Goes Pla](//)ces

Sample code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">First Link</a></td>
        <td>No Link</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that you have `table-layout:fixed` set on the table, and the width is not enough to hold the content inside, see the following demo for reproducing the issue.

```css
table {
    width: 30px; /*increase value*/
    table-layout: fixed; /*remove this*/
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">Link Link</a></td>
        <td>Text Text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**To fix the related issues in the demo:**

Either remove that `table-layout` rule or increase the `width`, or do both.

**Other things might be helping:**

Remove `white-space:nowrap;` if it's set somewhere related.

Set `word-break:break-all;` as needed, to force long words to break.

Answer (score -3):

There is nothing wrong with your code, can you show the issue page of this? So I can inspect your element...

Try reset css for the default table on your page

```css
table,
thead,
tbody,
tfoot,
tr,
th,
td {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    border-collapse: inherit;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-color: inherit;
    vertical-align: inherit;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: inherit;
    -webkit-border-horizontal-spacing: 0;
    -webkit-border-vertical-spacing: 0;
}
th, td {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer, it's a comment.

Comment: No I can't show the page of this since it's not on the front end (wordpress plugin). There are also no errors on the page (inspector)

Comment: @seer I can't insert the comment, because my reputation is not enough.. Try reset css on this page..

Comment: @MDCreativeIndonesia I understand, but that is for a reason. It is quite quick to overcome that limitation, and until you do, it's more useful if you find ways to make reputation that don't involve making "answers" that aren't actually answers.